# Having a problem with jquery datatables proper pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Trying to work around problem with datatables pagination. The problem is:

1. I have some code to initialize Datatable in Laravel:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.js-dataTable-full').DataTable({
                ajax: {
                    "url": "{{ route('page.data') }}",
                    "type": "GET",
                },
                "autoWidth": false,
                "serverSide": true,
                "pageLength": 5,
                "bSort": false,
                "searching": true,
                // "order": [[1, "desc"]],
                "processing": true,
                "paging": true,
                "pagingType": 'full_numbers',
    .......................................
    Some text below
```

2. The data is loaded correctly, however there's still an issue with pagination. [image]
   As you see, the pagination links are not active and cannot be clicked, though text on the left clearly says that there are only 5 of 8 entries on the page.
3. In the json response total number of items is present:

[image: Part of json response viewed from the browser tools]

No ideas by now, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can try to change recordsFiltered: 8 .

refer: https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data

Comment: Your JSON response says there are 8 records in total, but the list has been filtered to 5 records. Since you're showing 5 records per page, there is only one page to display. I suspect you're doing something wrong in your server-side code - unless you've entered a search term, I'd expect the `recordsFiltered` to be the same as the `recordsTotal`.